# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 in a Precision Tower with UEFI

Tags: uefi

I'm struggling to install Ubuntu 16.04 in a Workstation Precision 5820

I started with Secure Boot and UEFI Enabled and no Success. 
I tried with Secure Boot Disabled and UEFI Enabled and no Success

In both case the result is the same during the boot at certain point i have black screen with a blinking cursor on the top-left of the screen.
The only way to boot a media to install Ubuntu in Disable both Secure Boot and UEFI. There is any things that i can to so install Ubuntu with at least UEFI enabled?

Comment: Are you enabling LUKS encryption during the installation? And are you starting out with a plain Ubuntu 16.04.5?


FWIW, I have that same problem on that same computer. I think it has to do with the fact that the 5820 uses NVMe drives and not SATA. Anyway, I had to just use legacy BIOS booting instead of UEFI. However, none of these problems are present with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No Encryption, Just starting with a normal CD with Ubuntu 16.04.5. In this case we have only one Sata Disk, but we have also some with NVME. However the Boot of the LIVE CD work only in Legacy Mode. I have updated the BIOS, tried to add the parameter  nomodeset, but nothing. Still black Screen with blinking cursor at the top left..